# Rewrite URL from http://example.com/blog/ to http://blog.example.com/

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What `RewriteRule` (using `.htaccess`/`mod_rewrite`) should I use to redirect `http://example.com/blog/` (with `www` or without) to `http://blog.example.com/` ?

I'm using the following, but getting a redirect loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your existing rules you appear to have some stuff the wrong way around, and I don't think there's any need for the negative (i.e. `!`) test.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/$ http://blog.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

However I'd suggest that you don't use the `RewriteCond` directive to check the hostname, just make sure the rule is in the right `VirtualHost` for `www.example.com`.

```
<VirtualHost ...>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

RewriteRule ^/blog/ http://blog.example.com/ [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

(nb: assumes that `blog.example.com` and `www.example.com` are actually separate virtual hosts)